# What is the value of this sum? $\sum_{r=k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{r^{3/2} e^{\frac{c k}{2 r}}}$

Tags: summation

How can I calculate this, where $c>0$?

$$
\sum_{r=k}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{\frac{-c k}{2 r}}}{r^{3/2}}
$$

One solution might be to upper bound and lower bound this sum by an integral, and then take the limit which sandwiches both sides of the integral thus gives the limit of the sum. But, I don't know how to upper bound and lower bound the sum by integrals.

May be we can

$$
F(S_1,S_2) \leq \sum_{r=k}^{\infty}  \frac{e^{\frac{-c k}{2 r}}}{r^{3/2}} \leq G(S_1,S_2)
$$

where $S_1=\sum_{r=k}^{\infty}  \frac{1}{r^{3/2}}$ $S_2=\sum_{r=k}^{\infty}  {e^{\frac{-c k}{2 r}}}$and. Right?

Comment: i think you mean sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum has not a nice closed form, but we may approximate it with the integral:

$$ \int_{k}^{+\infty}r^{-3/2}e^{-\frac{ck}{2r}}\,dr = \int_{0}^{1/k}x^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{ck}{2}x}\,dx = \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{kc}}\,\text{Erf}\left(\sqrt{\frac{c}{2}}\right),$$
hence the sum, as a function of $k$, decays like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way that I can lower bound this sum by the integral you posted?

Comment: @Ramin: just replace $k$ with $k+1$.

Comment: I mean, instead of approximation, can I lower bound the sum by a similar integral? (which is not approximation )

Comment: @Ramin: I was meaning that the integral over $(k,+\infty)$ is an upper bound and the integral over $(k+1,+\infty)$ is a lower bound.

Comment: Why is that true? (the upper bound and lower bound)

Comment: @Ramin: because $r^{-3/2}$ is a decreasing function and the extra factor $e^{-(ck)/(2r)}$ doesn't change things much.

Comment: This is a rough idea. Can we see how exactly the sum in the problem statement is upper bounded or lower bounded by intergrals?

Comment: @Albert: think about it, I think I spent enough time on this.